# PyQT miss JS events

Tags: javascript, python, testing, pyqt

We are testing a quite complicated interface with a lot of JS code. We use PyQT (and its webkit). We simulate click events like that:

```
evaluateJavaScript("var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');  vObj.initEvent('click', true, true); this.dispatchEvent(evObj);")
```

And we fill forms with:

```
evaluateJavaScript('this.value = "%s"' % value)
```

Sometimes (unfortunately, very often) both of these tricks fail, sometimes one, sometimes another. We can't really understand the reason, it seems chaotic and random. Looks like those events sometimes don't execute. But the following events may execute fine. So it seems PyQT just 'drops' some events, missing them. It's really annoying, we simply can't perform tests. Does anybody know what is the reason? Or at least, how to execute the event and make sure it has really been executed? With setting value attr it's not a big deal, we can simply check if it has the value or not, but how to track whether 'click' was successful or not?

P.S. We don't use PhantomJS and won't use it because it lacks Flash support, getting it back  and rewriting our tests will take just too much time.

Thank you guys!